# Disable click event in list view that goes to Delve

Tags: list, sharepoint, view, web-parts, disable

I have a list that has names from Active Directory. When the view of the list is put on a web part page the name field is clickable, bringing the user to the home page of delve of the person. We would like to disable that so people don't go to Delve.

Can this be done with CSS to disable all opening events on list with exception of the list name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSR (Client Side Rendering) to override column rendering logic.

This is javascript code that can be added by different ways:
1. You can add Content Editor (or Script Editor) Web Part with this CSR javascript to list view page and your column will be changed.
2. You can open list view web part settings on list view page and in Miscellanious section set JSLink property to url of CSR javascript file.

CSR javascript file you can locate in some library, ex.Style Library or Site Assets.

CSR allow to change view, column rendering logic.

Now your field "name" rendered as link (`<a>` tag). You can override this logic. You can override logic to render as plain text or label or span or something not clickable.

If you don't want to learn CSR then use plain javascript to change your column rendering logic. Use same methods to add javascript to view but use plain javascript. Just define how to find your column on page and change it on page load.

By my opinion it is not good way but you can create text column and populate it by workflow. Like here:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218041/last-name-calculated-field-from-person-field/218045#218045
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a463eefe-4a07-40b7-a489-b896b93219ea/workaround-to-using-quotperson-or-groupquot-field-in-a-quotcalculatedquot-column-formula?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy

Later you can add this text column in view and remove clickable column from view.